# Where is the implicit GraphBuilder object passed from in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am learning the Akka Streams library and have the following confusion. I see a Graphbuilder object that is passed implicitly to the GraphDSL.create()(...) call. 
I am unable to understand where is the actual builder object made available from ?

```
 val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val in = Source(1 to 10)
  val out = Sink.ignore

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](2))

  val f1, f2, f3, f4 = Flow[Int].map(_ + 10)

  in ~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2 ~> merge ~> f3 ~> out
  bcast ~> f4 ~> merge
  ClosedShape
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah a look at the source makes it clearer.
The caller passes in the function while the instantiation of the builder is done from inside the `create` function.

From the `akka/stream/scaladsl/GraphApply.scala.template`

```
def create[S <: Shape]()(buildBlock: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] ⇒ S): Graph[S, NotUsed] = {
    val builder = new GraphDSL.Builder
    val s = buildBlock(builder)
    val mod = builder.module.replaceShape(s)

    new GraphApply.GraphImpl(s, mod)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `builder` is not implicitly needed from outside. If you take a look at the signature of the `create` function

```
def create[S <: Shape]()(buildBlock: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] ⇒ S): Graph[S, NotUsed]
```

you will notice that it only requires a function from a `Builder` to a `Shape`. In fact, if you remove the `implicit` keyword from your code, the call to `create` should still compile.

However, you need to make that builder available implicitly later on in your code, specifically when you need the GraphDSL notation `~>`. If you check the signature of `~>`

```
def ~>[U >: T](to: Inlet[U])(implicit b: Builder[_]): Unit
```

you will see this is where the implicit `Builder` is needed. This is why the `builder` parameter needs to be annotated as `implicit`.

Comment: Yeah i do understand that but what i guess i was trying to understand is who is providing the actual builder instance as input to the program ?   Is it made available by the implementation of `create` ?